# is there a function f:R→R , differentiable on (a,b) but not on [a,b] ?(f is continuous on [a,b])

Tags: calculus, derivatives

is there a function like f:R→R such that :
1) f is continuous on [a,b]
2) f is differentiable on (a,b)
3) f(a)=f(b)

but f is not differentiable on [a,b]??? (if the answer is no , then prove that f is also differentiable on [a,b])

this question came up in calculus 1 class and I think that f should be differentiable on [a,b] but can't prove it...
I don't know what is the condition 3 for!!!

Answer (score 1):

The standard example is a function like

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin(\frac{1}{x})x \quad &x\neq0\\ 0 &x=0\end{cases}$$

if you want to do the differential quotient at $0$ you get

$$\lim_{h\to 0} -\sin(\frac{1}{h})$$

which does not exist.

However the function is continuous on $[0,1]$ (because $\sin$ is bounded) and differentiable on $(0,1]$ because it is a composition of differentiable functions on that set.

I didn't see the condition three, that $f$ evaluates to the same value on the end points. This can also be gotten by not taking the interval $[0,1]$ but $[0,\frac{1}{\pi}]$ (or rescaling the function) since $\sin(\pi)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is:
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}
$$
defined on $[-1,1]$ (it's not difficult to extend it to the whole real line by pasting other semicircles). The derivative at the extremes doesn't exist, because the tangent line is vertical.